# Fantasy football draft

Tags: probability-theory

For 2 years in a row I have managed to draw the number 1 draft pick in my fantasy league. I want to know what the probability is of this happening.

Here is the info. For us to determine draft order each year in our fantasy football league we number pieces of paper from 1 to 12.  These papers are made into balls and put into a hat.  Now, since I was in first place last year, I had to draw the last ball, I.e, all the other players drew before me. So the last place team drew first, when all teams had drawn there was only one ball left for me and it was the #1.

The second year I drew 10th, and again I got the #1 ball for the second year in a row even after 9 players drew before me.  What is the probability of this happening 2 years in a row?

Answer (score 1):

The order of draws does not matter at all.  You have $\frac 1{12}$ chance of getting the first pick each year.  Before the first draw, you have $\frac 1{12^2}$ chance of getting the first pick the next two years in a row.  However, you would probably remark on it if the same person got the first pick twice.  That has a chance of $\frac 1{12}$ as somebody has to get the first pick the first year.  Then we only need that person to win again the next year.